# How to solve my problem,My for loop repeat more than it's steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a confirm dialog by jquery and bootstrap. when the user click on 'Yes' or 'No' it should do something.
for example draw two squares every time.at first time when I click 'Yes' or 'NO' Button it draws 2 squares, but when i repeat it draws four squares at second try , and six squares at 3rd try ... in addition to previous squares.
Html
    Click
    
JQuery

```
    $('button').click(function() {
    optionsArrSize = 2;
    customConfirm(function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {

            //do somethings
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < optionsArrSize; i++) {
            $('body').append('<div style=" display: inline-block;width: 30px;height: 30px;margin:5px;background: blue"><div>')

        }
    })
})
function customConfirm(callback) {
    var confBox="<div class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='mySmallModalLabel'  id='myModal'>" +
        "    <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>" +
        "        <div class='modal-content'>" +
        "            <div class='modal-header'>" +
        "                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" +
        "                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>warning</h4>" +
        "            </div><div class='modal-body'>Draw Two squares?</div>" +
        "            <div class='modal-footer'>" +
        "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btnYes' id='btnYes'>Yes</button>" +
        "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btnNo' id='btnNo'>No</button>" +
        "            </div>" +
        "        </div>" +
        "    </div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='alert' role='alert' id='result'></div>";
    $('.appendBox').append(confBox);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $(document).on('click','.btnYes',function () {
        callback(true);
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    });
    $(document).on('click','.btnNo',function () {
        callback(false);
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');

    });
}
```

```js
    $('button').click(function() {
        optionsArrSize = 2;
        customConfirm(function (confirmed) {
            if (confirmed) {

                //do somethings
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < optionsArrSize; i++) {
                $('body').append('<div style=" display: inline-block;width: 30px;height: 30px;margin:5px;background: blue"><div>')

            }
        })
    })
    function customConfirm(callback) {
        var confBox="<div class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='mySmallModalLabel'  id='myModal'>" +
            "    <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>" +
            "        <div class='modal-content'>" +
            "            <div class='modal-header'>" +
            "                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" +
            "                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>warning</h4>" +
            "            </div><div class='modal-body'>Draw Two squares?</div>" +
            "            <div class='modal-footer'>" +
            "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btnYes' id='btnYes'>Yes</button>" +
            "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btnNo' id='btnNo'>No</button>" +
            "            </div>" +
            "        </div>" +
            "    </div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='alert' role='alert' id='result'></div>";
        $('.appendBox').append(confBox);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $(document).on('click','.btnYes',function () {
            callback(true);
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        });
        $(document).on('click','.btnNo',function () {
            callback(false);
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');

        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">Click</button>
<div class="container appendBox"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Note you are continually appending a new `confBox` but never getting ride of the previously added one, just hiding it(it still exists in the dom). And since the previous ones still exist you are adding more click events to the same button(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just changed:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnYes',function () {
```

to:

```
 $(document).find('#myModal').on('click','.btnYes',function () {
```

and used html() instead of append();
It work properly.
if we use unbide() or one() on the $(document) other buttons of our document will get disabled.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
        $(document).on('click','#sq',function() {
            optionsArrSize = 2;
            customConfirm(function (confirmed) {
                if (confirmed) {

                    console.log(optionsArrSize)
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < optionsArrSize; i++) {
                    $('body').append('<div style=" display: inline-block;width: 30px;height: 30px;margin:5px;background: blue"><div>')

                }
            })
        })
        function customConfirm(callback) {
            var confBox="<div class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='mySmallModalLabel'  id='myModal'>" +
                "    <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>" +
                "        <div class='modal-content'>" +
                "            <div class='modal-header'>" +
                "                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" +
                "                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>warning</h4>" +
                "            </div><div class='modal-body'>Draw Two squares?</div>" +
                "            <div class='modal-footer'>" +
                "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btnYes' id='btnYes'>Yes</button>" +
                "                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btnNo' id='btnNo'>No</button>" +
                "            </div>" +
                "        </div>" +
                "    </div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='alert' role='alert' id='result'></div>";
            $('.appendBox').html(confBox);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $(document).find('#myModal').on('click','.btnYes',function () {
                callback(true);
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            });
            $(document).find('#myModal').on('click','.btnNo',function () {

                callback(false);
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');

            });
        }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id='sq'>Click</button>
<div class="container appendBox"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are creating blue boxes on `button` click. So, the code will get invoked for `click` button as well when you click `yes` button and `no` button.

Instead add your blue box creation code only when `yes` button from confirmation is clicked and not on `$('button').click(function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

On every execution of `customConfirm`, new listeners are attached to the document (without removing the old ones). It's not the loop being executed too many times, it's this function:

```
        $(document).on('click','.btnYes',function () {
            callback(true);
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        });
```

Maybe refactor it into something like

```
$('.btnYes').off('click').on('click', // old handler here
```

Comment: what is old handler here?

Comment: The function from two lines above, the last argument of `$(document).on('click','.btnYes', //)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .one like so, so the click registers only once:

```
    // USE .one TO PREVENT ANY DUPLICATE ONCLICK EVENT LISTENER
    $(document).one('click','.btnYes',function () {
        callback(true);
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    });
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/tamak/3rm9L2eg/).

Answer updated to instead use .one -- the commenter had a valid concern with my proposed use of unbind.   The working example code is updated as well

Comment: Shouldnt use unbind like this, you would just be recreating the same functions needlessly. Since the modal they are creating never really changes nor the event handlers just add the modal from the start and simply show/hide that same one. This way you only need to set the event handlers once

Comment: is not necessary to unbind btnNo ?

Comment: @Hamid I dont see a need to do that, but another thing I fixed in my example was to move the for loop inside the if(confirmed).  To prevent clicking 'No' from adding new blue boxes.  Someone mentioned my solution creating same functions needlessly, I see that point, but there's no real 'cost' to doing it this way, so it would be my choice, valid point though.

Comment: @Hamid - instead of unbind, use $(document).one('click', '.btnYes', function() { ... it addresses the issue and only allows ONE event listener.   My answer has been  updated.

Comment: @tamak No, the previous version of your answer is correct. this one will unbind only btnYes. and btnNo still draws more than two squares each time

Comment: @tamak, a problems that will appear . when we unbide the click event of document. other buttons will get disable(unbind)

Comment: @Hamid - try the .one  instead of unbind -- see the updated code in my answer above

Comment: @tamak ,I have find the solution. You can see it on my answer.